# check how many dominant numbers there are in a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

in this program i'm supposed to find how many dominant numbers the matrix has. a dominant number is a number that is bigger than whatever is below to the right onwards(bear with my english please).

i entered this :

```
5 (9) 2  4  1 (7)  2  4///
3  5  6  2  5 (6)  1  2///
1  3  4  7  8 (8) (3) 0///
1  3  5  6  7  8   2  1///
```

the ones i circled are supposed to be the dominant ones but it gave me back 6, what went wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NR 4
#define NC 8

int dominants(int a[NR][NC]);
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
int array[NR][NC];
int ndom;
int i,j;


for(i=0;i<NR;i++){
        for(j=0;j<NC;j++){

        scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
        }
}
printf("array entered:\n\n");
for(i=0;i<NR;i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<NC;j++){

        printf("%d  ", array[i][j]);
        }
}

ndom=dominants(array);

printf("amount of dominant numbers:%d", ndom);
return 0;
}
int dominants(int a[NR][NC]){
int domflag;
int i,j, l, m;
int numdom=0;
for(i=0;i<NR-1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<NC-1;j++){
        for(l=i+1;l<NR;l++){
                domflag=1;
                for(m=j+1;m<NC;m++){
                if(a[i][j]<=a[l][m]){
                    domflag=0;
                                    }
                                   }
                           }
            if(domflag==1){
                numdom++;
                          }
        }

    }
    return numdom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`domflag = 1;` is inside the loop `for (l = i + 1; l < NR; l++)` but should be outside it.

A good way to reduce errors like this is to only define identifiers where they are needed. If the definition `int domflag;` at the top of the routine were removed and the statement `domflag = 1;` were changed to `int domflag = 1;`, then the compiler would have given an error later where `domflag == 1` is tested, because that would be outside the scope of the definition.

Answer (score -1):

Do not put all the logic into the main function. Try to use functions. It makes things much easier

```
int isdominant(int *arr, size_t cols, size_t rows, size_t col, size_t row)
{
    int *rowend = arr + (row + 1) * cols - 1;
    int *pos = arr + row * cols + col;
    while(rowend > pos)
        if(*pos <= *rowend--) return 0;
    return 1;
}

#define COLS 10
#define ROWS 7

int main()
{
    int arr[ROWS][COLS];
    int *ptr = &arr[0][0];
    unsigned dominants = 0;


    for(size_t index = 0; index < ROWS * COLS; index++) *ptr++ = rand() % 50;

    for(size_t row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
        {
            int dom = 0;
            if(col != COLS - 1) dom = isdominant(arr[0], COLS, ROWS, col, row);
            printf("%s%d%s\t", dom ? "(" : "", arr[row][col], dom ? ")" : "");
            dominants += dom;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Dominant numbers: %u\n", dominants);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/tpwnm2

Comment: (a) Gets the wrong answer on the input given in the question because it allows elements in the last row to be dominant (the original code requires the below-right submatrices be non-empty). (b) Gets wrong answers on other inputs because it compares the candidate to only one row, rather than to the below-right submatrix, as the original code tries. (c) Needlessly uses pointers and pointer arithmetic without explaining to a student at this level. (d) Absurd rewrite of the code (without documentation) that does not answer OP’s question of “what went wrong?” by explaining the error in their code.